How to get the stack pointer and return address and restore them to a previous state
I'm trying to implement a poor man's call with current continuation for a program written in C.  I can "easily" access and memcpy the relevant part of the C stack (obviously, that's not portable and is full of UB, but I already bit that bullet).
What I'm wondering is how to get the actual stack pointer and return address and how to restore them.  I have the impression that I can probably get away with doing it only for the stack pointer (the return address itself will be hopefully stashed inside the stack chunk that I copied&restored).
I suspect this will require a bit of assembly, but I'm hoping that there's ideally some clever way to avoid it.

I'd remove the "or that there's a library out there which does the ugly bits for me, or in the worst case some existing code I could copy which has similar needs and has the needed inline ASM for the usual-suspect ISAs" part since it's close-bait. If someone knows about such a library, I'm sure they'll speak up anyway.

Since as you say this is not portable, you should mention and tag the implementation(s) you want to target. If it's only tagged [tag:c], it's assumed you are working entirely within the ISO standard.

Couldn't this be done (in a non-portable way, of course) with setjmp? I mean, it is almost the same thing as call/cc, but (and that a big but) for the fact that you can only go down the stack (so, you can go back to the caller, or the caller of the caller, or... ; but not, contrarily to call/cc,  go "back" to a previously called function. The stack with setjmp is still the same classical stack, just you can fast unstack it. It is not the implicit tree that "stack" is with call/cc)

But, still, setjmp stores everything you need (stack pointer, registers, etc.). It is UB if used with an obsolete stack, but may be combining that with the ugly stack copy you intend to do...

Are you interested in protothreads? https://dunkels.com/adam/pt/

This can be achieved using ucontext. It doesn't allow you to manipulate the stack so much as it allows you to switch between different combos of stack and execution address combos. I demo using it to create coroutines (co-operative multitasking) here.

Smells like an "xy question". What is the actual problem you are trying to solve here? Are you implementing a RTOS context switch or similar?

@chrslg: Thank you thank you thank you!  Feel free to turn this into an answer.  Not sure why I didn't think of it, but indeed setjmp should do exactly what I need.  After memcpying the old copy of the stack (previously memcpied at the same time as I did the setjmp) back into the current stack I should be able to use longjmp to "resurrect" the old state.

@NateEldredge: I'd like it to work on Windows, Android, macOS, GNU/Linux (OS-wise) and armhf, arm64, riscv, i386, and amd64 (ISA-wise), both with GCC and LLVM.  Not sure how to tag this "implementation".

@ikegami: Thanks for the pointer to get/setcontext.  I wasn't aware of those newer alternatives to (sig)longjmp.

Per request, my comments in the form of an answer (tho, you are doing something so specific that I doubt that anybody with the same question will ever read it :D)
This could probably be done (in a non-portable way, of course) with setjmp/longjmp. I mean, it is almost the same thing as call/cc, but (and that a big but) for the fact that you can only go down the stack. So, you can go back to the caller, or the caller of the caller, or... ; but not, contrarily to call/cc, go "back" to a previously called function, in a stack as non-linear as Marty McFly's timeline is. The stack with setjmp is still the same classical, linear, stack, just you can fast unstack it. It is not the implicit tree that "stack" is with call/cc
But, still, setjmp stores everything you need (stack pointer, registers, etc.). It is UB if used with an obsolete stack, but may be combining that with the ugly stack copy you intend to do...
